# Cannot access POST data using NodeJS/Express and HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In my application, I have a form with the action pointing to a nodejs endpoint. It is sucessfully performing the action, but when i try to extract the posted data from `req`, it refuses to give me anything. I may just be looking in the wrong place.

Here is my HTML

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hello, you are here</h1>
    <form action="/archive_message" method="post">
        Message URL: <input type="text" name="urlToProcess">
        <select>
            <option name="process-method" value="msg">Message</option>
            <option name="process-method" value="trd">Thread</option>
            <option name="process-method" value="act">Account</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

here is my js

```js
server.start().then(res => {
   server.applyMiddleware({app})
   app.listen(8081, function () {   
      console.log("Running!");
   })
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html");
   console.log("200 - GET");
});


app.post('/archive_message', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body.urlToProcess);
   res.redirect("/");
})
```

When i log `req.body`, i just get header info, when i try to dig further, i get errors. How am i supposed to be accessing the data submitted by the form?

specifically, i am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'urlToProcess')`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using the bodyparser middleware?

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly the problem, but "name" applies to the "select" element, not "option".

Comment: I am not familiar with that. Do you have a link i could check out? @Barmar

Comment: @user1751825 thank you. that is not what is causing this issue, but you are correct that i need to fix that. Thank you

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: See the *very first paragraph* of the [documentation about `body`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body).

Answer (score -1):

try this one
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));